# Consider putting tex.stackexchange.com in thesis acknowledgements

Tags: discussion, community

I'd like to add this fantastic forum and community for all the help with typesetting and formatting my thesis. Is there a defined way to do it/refer to TeX ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Should this be on Meta? Also, search 'colophon' on this site; I'm mobile and can't bring it up, but there is a pretty cool Q about this sort of thing.

Comment: I did [something like this](http://i.imgur.com/3CoMN4E.png) at that time :)

Comment: I have thanks to `\TeX{} wizards at stackexchange: \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}` in the acknowledgments of a book I'm working on.

Comment: I also put tex.stackexchange links in my package documentation.

Comment: Related [How do I properly cite TeX.SE for its help in typesetting?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3281/15717)

Comment: I don't know if @SeanAllred is referring to this [What is best way to mention that a document has been typeset with TeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63468/15717)

Comment: @texenthusiast That's the one! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I was considering doing this too (printing now) -- but I decided not to do it.  Typesetting help is wonderful, but in the usual case it's not *quite* a research-level contribution.  Maybe you'd consider adding the relevant credits to an "About the Document" section at the end instead?

Comment: Acknowledgements are not about the research but for creating the result. Otherwise you shouldn't mention your family, friends, your department secretary etc. Presenting the ideas better contribute to the research anyways.